# Flutter firestore Pagination with Streambuilder, Load more than one image in advance

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, stream-builder

I'm new to flutter and i added pagination to my streambuilder, which displays images that have been accessed from firestore storage. Currently, the pagination only lazy loads one image in advance, how do I make it load the next 3 images, while im viewing the current image I am on. Ideally, as a user scrolls through each image, there should always be atleast 3 images that have been lazy loaded, so there is no visible lag.

Here is my code, and yes, I am aware the same screen is being displayed in both tab views, I havent done the functionality for the second tab view yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FeedScreen> createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  PageController _scrollController = PageController();

  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset >=
              (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        _getChats();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  final StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _chatController =
      StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();
  List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _allPagedResults = [<DocumentSnapshot>[]];

  static const int chatLimit = 2;
  DocumentSnapshot? _lastDocument;
  bool _hasMoreData = true;

  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> listenToChatsRealTime() {
    _getChats();
    return _chatController.stream;
  }

  void _getChats() {
    final CollectionReference _chatCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts");

    var pagechatQuery = _chatCollectionReference
        .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
        .limit(chatLimit);

    if (_lastDocument != null) {
      pagechatQuery = pagechatQuery.startAfterDocument(_lastDocument!);
    }
    if (!_hasMoreData) return;

    var currentRequestIndex = _allPagedResults.length;
    pagechatQuery.snapshots().listen(
      (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          var generalChats = snapshot.docs.toList();

          var pageExists = currentRequestIndex < _allPagedResults.length;

          if (pageExists) {
            _allPagedResults[currentRequestIndex] = generalChats;
          } else {
            _allPagedResults.add(generalChats);
          }

          var allChats = _allPagedResults.fold<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
              <DocumentSnapshot>[],
              (initialValue, pageItems) => initialValue..addAll(pageItems));

          _chatController.add(allChats);

          if (currentRequestIndex == _allPagedResults.length - 1) {
            _lastDocument = snapshot.docs.last;
          }

          _hasMoreData = generalChats.length == chatLimit;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 32,
                )),
            bottom: const TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromARGB(155, 255, 255, 255),
                indicatorColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        'Following',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text('Explore',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                  stream: listenToChatsRealTime(),
                  builder: (context, chatSnapshot) {
                    if (chatSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }

                    return PageView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: chatSnapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => FeedCard(
                        snap: chatSnapshot.data![index].data(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                  stream: listenToChatsRealTime(),
                  builder: (context, chatSnapshot) {
                    if (chatSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }

                    return PageView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: chatSnapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => FeedCard(
                        snap: chatSnapshot.data![index].data(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, when I'm viewing an image, it will only load the next image. I do not know how to make it so it loads the following 3 images. Each image takes up the entire screen.

Comment: why not to use [cache extent](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/cacheExtent.html)?

Comment: @pskink I wasnt aware that cache extent existed, does it allow you to load more than just the next image ? E.g Loads the next three images before i scroll to them?

Comment: i think so, you can play with that and see how it works - the best idea is to add some `print` inside `itemBuilder` and see when it is called

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).